# Fatal Error Class 'VARIANT' not found

Tags: php

I am using PHPmaker 10 and Microsoft Access 2007

After generating my project I got an error message as when running it

> Fatal error: Class 'VARIANT' not found in ... on line 42

Please help me.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Without any code we can do little to help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable following extension in php.ini,

`extension=php_com_dotnet.dll`